# Cannot install Tribler - missing dependencies

Tags: software-installation, 18.04

trying to install this https://www.tribler.org/ on Ubuntu 18.04 but I get this error:

[image]

And I can't find any repo for libsodium

```
tio@tio:~$ sudo apt install libsodium18
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libsodium18 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libsodium18' has no installation candidate
tio@tio:~$ sudo apt install libsodium13
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libsodium13 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libsodium13' has no installation candidate
tio@tio:~$
```

I reported [issue 3864 to GitHub tracker](https://github.com/Tribler/tribler/issues/3864).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tested pre-release version. It works out the box:

```
wget https://github.com/Tribler/tribler/releases/download/v7.1.0-rc1/tribler_7.1.0-rc1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./tribler_7.1.0-rc1_all.deb
```

and launch it:

[image: Tribler on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE]

it has fully-functional tray icon with drop-down menu (at least on MATE):

[image: Tribler on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS MATE - tray icon]

Notes: currently [bug 3864](https://github.com/Tribler/tribler/issues/3864) is fixed, and fix will be included in next stable version.

Comment: Thank you. For the first option I get this error about vlc http://i.imgur.com/F37OuJy.png and if I try to install vlc I get more errors http://i.imgur.com/zuf2JEZ.png

Comment: Please enable *universe* repository with `sudo add-apt-repository universe`, then update package lists with `sudo apt-get update`, install all new upgrades with new dependencies with `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and install Tribler.

Comment: The thing is that I have Universe enabled. And all updates and upgrades are up to date.

Comment: I suspect it is an issuw with vlc since I can't install that either - http://i.imgur.com/UZ5Pwod.png . I don't know why that is and why is tribler depending on vlc?

Comment: I can recommend you to [ask new question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with the problem of VLC installation. Add output of the `sudo apt-get install vlc` to it (in text, no pictures).

Answer (score 1):

After I fixed the issue with VLC - [Cannot install VLC on Ubuntu 18.04 - missing dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073669/cannot-install-vlc-on-ubuntu-18-04-missing-dependencies/) I used this and it worked

```
wget https://github.com/Tribler/tribler/releases/download/v7.1.0-rc1/tribler_7.1.0-rc1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./tribler_7.1.0-rc1_all.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

This package is not compatible with Ubuntu 18.04, as it depends on `libsodium13` or `libsodium18`, but Ubuntu 18.04 has `libsodium23`. You should contact the developers of the package to let them know of this issue, and hopefully they will release a fixed version.